# How to get multiple ajax request with promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get a single image from each ajax request and append it to a li box container, the first ajax returns a list of 20 objects, with name and a url

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/",
  dataType: "json",
  method: "GET",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i<data.results.length ;i++){
      $("#root ul").append('<li class="box"></li>');
      $("li").eq(i).append('<h2>' + data.results[i].name +'</h2>');
    }
    setPkmImage(data.results);
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(data) {
    console.log("Error");
  }

});
```

The problem starts when I try to make a call for each of those objects to request an image, it works with the async: false, but i don't want to do it that way since it takes a lot of time to load all the images.

```
function setPkmImage(res){
  for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

    var promise = $.ajax({
      url: res[i].url,
      dataType: "json",
      method: "GET",
      cache: false,
      //async: false,
      promise.done( function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#root ul");
        $("li").eq(i).append('<img src="' + data.sprites.front_default+ '"/>');

      });
      promise.fail( function(data) {
        console.log("Error");
      });

    });
   }
  }
```

I'm trying to use promises but I don't know exactly how to structure it

Comment: Is the only problem that the images all get put in the last `<li>`? You need a closure loop as per [Javascript closure inside loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: they dont even get on the li, it gets an error at the first promise.done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two major problems, one is syntax and the other is you need a closure loop

First the `$.ajax` is not closed properly.

Should look more like:

```
 var promise = $.ajax({
      url: res[i].url,
      dataType: "json",
      method: "GET",
      cache: false
 });

 promise.done(...
 promise.fail(...
```

As for the closure loop, `i` won't be what you want it to be inside the ajax callbacks because the `for` loop will have been completed before the data for requests is returned. Thus `i` will be at it's maximum by then

Try changing the `for` loop to `$.each` which creates a closure

```
$.each(res, function(i, item){

       var promise = $.ajax({
          url: item.url,
          dataType: "json",
          method: "GET",
          cache: false
     });

     promise.done(...
     promise.fail(...

})
```

Comment: Thank you, this was what i was looking for, none of the questions I looked at used $.each, I'll look into its documentation to see how it works exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the next solution. After first request is done, I've insert to dom img with url (url is come from request) and browser will load images automatically.

Comment: the first request gives me [this](http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/) array, it doesnt have the images, I need to do another call to get them

Comment: ah, sorry. i've not fully understand you problem.